# Is there a rule of thumb size limit to the javascript libraries/plugins I want to include on my website pages?

Tags: javascript

I often have the jquery library included for my page, roughly 75kb or so. Lately, I'm looking into the need to add more javascript libraries/plugins I found online, which I'm looking at adding another 25kb. In doing so, I would be concerned of adding sizes will increase the loading time for my site. Is there a 'rule of thumb' upper size limit I should be considering so I don't add any more unneeded loading time?

Comment: jQuery should be only about 30kB according to the docs. Make sure you minify and gzip all the scripts you load.

Comment: Focus on load times, not on file sizes.  If your site is still fast with the additional file, great!  If not, look into things like script consolidation, minification, and caching optimization.

Answer (score 1):

My rule has always been, **use only what you need**.

If you can achieve the goals of your application without something, don't use it.  If an important feature set relies on a heavy library, use it.

Of course, no matter what, always make sure your JS files are gzip (or equivalent) compressed by your server, and use minified files as well.

Finally, it is important to keep your audience in mind.  Good usage of analytics will reveal whether or not your users are tolerating your page load times.

Answer (score 0):

No general rules I could suggest other than to keep it as small as is possible and don't link in libraries you don't intend to use.

If you are using common libraries, link your libraries from a common third party like the [Google Libraries API](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/).  It is likely that many of your end users may already have the library versions you link from there cached in their browsers, improving their load times.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit to the size (You can have it 1GB if you wanted), but generally I'd keep it as very small as possible.

Some tips to optimize scripts:

- **Minify** - This means shortening variable names, remove whitespaces and so on. Dean Edwards' [/packer/](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) is an example. I'd suggest Google Closure Compiler also, but I'd reserve it for post-production phase since it will alter the code structure.
- **Merge** - Compile your scripts so that they are contained, in the very least, only one file. This saves you a ton of HTTP requests later.
- **Use what you only need** -  If, for example, you only need a few parts of jQuery, they have [an option to roll out your own jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) (somewhere in the docs). Another example of this is jQueryUI, where you have an option to load selected UI features.

Comment: Good luck getting your site to load well on mobile devices if you have 1GB to load.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about a 'rule of thumb' but you should certainly be asking yourself the following questions:

- Are your scripts [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29)?
- Are external scripts being linked externally?
- Can these be linked from a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)?

For example you're much better off letting [someone else host a library like jQuery](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/), as that lets your own server deal with only serving your content.

But most of all **include only the absolute minimum** you need for the functionality of your site.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to make an estimation since we do not know what functionality your library offers. However you can compare it with jQuery. It offers so much cross browser functionality as a 30 kb file.

Every file you add to the page will take some time to transfer. It can be reduced by caching, minification,CDNs etc. Also there are approaches that bundles all JavaScript files into one. This significantly improves performance by reducing request number.